# Is it bad practice to use a using statement on a class level variable?

Tags: c#, scope, using

I have code similar to the following.

```
class MyController
{
    [ThreadStatic] private DbInterface db;

    public void ImportAllData()
    {
        using (db = new DbInterface())
        {
            var records = PullData();
            PushData(records);
        }
    }

    private DbRecord[] PullData()
    {
        return db.GetFromTableA();
    }

    private void PushData(DbRecord[] records)
    {
        db.InsertIntoTableB(records);
    }
}
```

The alternative is a lot more cumbersome to maintain.

```
class MyController
{
    public void ImportAllData()
    {
        using (var db = new DbInterface())
        {
            var records = PullData(db);
            PushData(records, db);
        }
    }

    private DbRecord[] PullData(DbInterface db)
    {
        return db.GetFromTableA();
    }

    private void PushData(DbRecord[] records, DbInterface db)
    {
        db.InsertIntoTableB(records);
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, my first implementation:

- is thread safe (assuming `DbInterface` is thread safe),
- prevents any other process from touching the `db` variable, and
- ensures `db` will always be disposed, even during an exception.

Is it bad practice to use the `using` statement on a variable with class scope?  Have I missed something?

Comment: Considered using an extension? Or do you plan on doing this a lot.

Comment: Interestingly, if you ever do Win Forms painting code, The OnPaint and Paint events are very much like this, at least in regards to passing the ref outside the using block.  You are passed a graphics context that was allocated for you and whose management/disposal is handled by the caller and therefore you do not dispose it yourself in the actual painting methods.

Comment: @DanSaltmer, I plan on using the `DbInterface` class in other controllers.  I want the controllers to have access to all `DbInterface` methods, but I don't want to controllers to know about each others private methods.  To my understanding, extension methods would apply to all `DbInterface` instances.  Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @tcarvin, I can relate to that.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have to use `ThreadStatic` on a static field? I suspect that the first variant is actually not thread-safe.

Comment: @mikez, you're right.  That further endorses the second solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I prefer your second option.

The issue with the first design is that your effectively adding unnecessary coupling to the design.  Your `PullData` and `PushData` methods cannot be used alone - they *require* that a call to `ImportAllData` or some other method that will setup and properly cleanup the `db` variable be called first.

The second option, while *slightly* more code (though not much), makes the intent very clear for each and every method.  Each method knows that it needs to work on an external `DbInterface` instance passed into it.  There is little or no chance of this being misused in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Your first variant exposes `db` outside of the scope where it is managed by the `using` block.  That opens the possibility of unintended side effects.  For example, another method might use or even dispose of db.  That could happen if you or a later maintainer forget the implicit contract for `db` or even through a typo in code.

I would not use the first variant.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative:

```
sealed class MyImporter
{
    private readonly DbInterface db;

    public MyImporter(DbInterface db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void ImportAllData()
    {
        var records = PullData();
        PushData(records);
    }

    private DbRecord[] PullData()
    {
        return db.GetFromTableA();
    }

    private void PushData(DbRecord[] records)
    {
        db.InsertIntoTableB(records);
    }
}
```

In this case, holding onto the reference is a clear part of the class responsibility.  It's also now pushing up the responsibility of disposal to the user.  This more explicit construct reduces the temptation to add additional features to the 'Controller', which is how your first approach can go bad in the long run.  Essentially we've refactored the Import function into a separate class so that the shared field access is no longer a problem.

Comment: +1: I would also add dependency injection into the constructor: public MyImporter(DbInterface _db)
    {
        db = _db;
    }

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, agreed, that's actually much cleaner; it actually eliminates the need to have Disposal inside the class, as well

Comment: This moves the responsibility of disposing of `db` to the caller.  May be a good or bad thing, but it is a change in class responsibilities.  If the caller doesn't know how to create an instance of `db`, this pattern would not work.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the construct is there for. I would be careful about putting a using into property, since convention dictates that property access is lightweight and the user does not necesarily want to trigger a create-dispose cycle when they think they're just accessing a variable.

However the comments below about the structure of the code are important - if you want to do the import once, it becomes a setup step that users need to know about. If you can envision different access patterns the dependency injection setup allows the user to control the creation and disposal of the connections.